# TFS on virtual machine?

Tags: tfs, sharepoint-2010, virtual-machine

A follow developer friend is trying to learn the TFS 2010 API.

We have established the following trial Virtual machine together:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=509c3ba1-4efc-42b5-b6d8-0232b2cbb26e&displaylang=en#QuickDetails

In our first test, we would like to read the set of bugs from a TFS project using C#.

Does TFS 2010 depend upon sharepoint being correctly configured on the server?

If so, is there an easy process for setting up sharePoint and relating it to TFS?

Any helpful direction you can offer would be greatly appreciated.

Wish you the best!

Comment: I have that VM running myself. SharePoint is installed and running on it. Please post the smallest piece of code you can that reproduces the problem, and include the full exception being received.

Answer (score 0):

Just install sharepoint services 3 on the same server as TFS. It all works fine on a virtual server, I had it running with SQL and IIS on a VMWARE install with no hassles.